# Cannot search tasks for assignedToID: null

Tags: attask, workfront-api

I'm trying to fetch all unassigned tasks by specifying "assignedToID": null in my get request. But it always returns empty array...the fun thing is - it doesn't work only with null, if I use an user id it fetches correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing the value 'null' to assignedToID, use assignedToID_Mod=isnull.